# Snippets - Identifier has already been declared

Tags: google-chrome

I wrote this in a Chrome snippet:

```
let myVar = someValue;
```

And when I try to run it 2nd time, it says the variable has already been declared and throws an error at first line.

The error is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'myVar' has already
> been declared
> at :1:1

And of course, this would be the default behavior for the Console but it doesn't seem to make much sense here..

Is this intended? Is there any way around this?

Comment: just put your code inside `(function(){ //your code })();`

Answer (score 30):

Use block scope and wrap it in '{}'.

```
{
  enter code here
}
```

Answer (score 22):

I believe you're running into the fact that a `let` statement can only be used to create a variable once in any given scope. In your example, even though you're using Chrome snippets, if you output `window.commitPromotionData` right after the `let` statement you'll see that it is there. That's the scope your `let` statement is assigning the variable to. Re-running the same snippet essentially tries to create the same variable within window and results in syntax error as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let).

You have two workarounds:

1. Obviously the first is to convert any top level `let` statements to `var`'s
2. Or create a new block scope for wrapping the code. This can be done for instance by wrapping the code in an IIFE `(function(){ ... code ... })()`

Comment: This can be done for instance by wrapping the code in a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#Block_Scoping_Rules) `{ ... code ... }`

Comment: It seems they've finally addressed this:

https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools/status/1192426360674885632?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Eembeddedtimeline%7Ctwcon%5Etimelinechrome&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fv8.dev%2F

Answer (score 2):

The error is that you declared variable twice in the scope.

You can reload or refresh the page, then you get new scope, the error will vanish.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because somewhere in another snippet you used a variable with the same name. Make sure you save your snippet and then refresh the page.

To stop this from happening use `{}` around your snippet's code to create a block so that variable inside it aren't accessible from outside.

Answer (score 1):

simply pause the script execution. which is on the top right of the console

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Chrome already breaks when not using {} scope. To fix it you need to close and remove the snippet and open a new snippet and paste the code of the previous one

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue but my wrong was that I mistakenly linked same js file two times-- one at the top(inside the HTML head tag) and another before the  tag. I removed the linked js from the head tag and left the one before the `</body>` tag and my code worked.
This may be unrelated to other answers but sometimes we as humans, this kind of oversight as mine could be the issue.

In other news, here is a [tweet](https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools/status/1192426360674885632?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Eembeddedtimeline%7Ctwcon%5Etimelinechrome&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fv8.dev%2F) by Google Chrome that indicates that this issue has been addressed.

Answer (score -7):

**LONG SHORT SHOT :**
WHEN THAT ERROR POP UP'S JUST CLICK THE **SOURCE OPTION** BESIDE **CONSOLE** AND **PAUSE THE EXCEPTIONS** WHICH IS **7th OPTION** FROM LEFT, NOW YOU ARE GOOD TO WORK :).GO TO **CONSOLE AND EXECUTE** YOUR PROGRAM IT WORKS PERFECTLY FINE.....

Comment: Please don't write comments in all caps; it's understood to be "shouting."