# console log in javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function, syntax-error

```
const getAverage = (numberOne, numberTwo) => {
    const average = (numberOne + numberTwo) / 2 ;
    console.log(average);
};

getAverage(365, 27);
// Output: 196

const getAverage = (numberOne, numberTwo) => {
    const average = (numberOne + numberTwo) / 2 ;
    return average;
};

getAverage(365, 27);
// Output:  SyntaxError: Identifier 'getAverage' has already been declared
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

why?

Comment: What is the error thrown exactly ?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear, could you be more specific? see [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for future questions.

Comment: Should not give you any error. Just that when you return something, you have to do something with the return. In your case, you can use console.log and pas the function call to log the result `console.log(getAverage(365, 27))`. You have a Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jfz429zk/)

Comment: so what is the difference between saying getAverage(365, 27); and console.log(getAverage2(365, 27));??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Snippets - Identifier has already been declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699451/snippets-identifier-has-already-been-declared)

Answer (score 0):

If those functions are in the same location, then your problem is you're using the same function name.

```js
const getAverage = (numberOne, numberTwo) => {
 const average = (numberOne + numberTwo) / 2 ;
 console.log(average);
};

getAverage(365, 27);


const getAverage2 = (numberOne, numberTwo) => {
    const average = (numberOne + numberTwo) / 2 ;
    return average;
};

console.log(getAverage2(365, 27));
```