# LocalHost + AngularJS & ngRoute + AdBlock + Chrome = error

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, localhost, ngroute, adblock

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'chunkSize' has already been declared
    at VM[...] adblock-datacollection-contentscript.js:1
(anonymous) @ VM[...] adblock-datacollection-contentscript.js:1
```

if I use ngRoute and click on any button [ul>li>a] with attribute href="#!something", it always create error in console (when my website run on localhost (Apache server) and open in chrome with any adblock.)

It's pointing to file: https://gist.github.com/Mlocik97-issues/4d5e392a8cb1b547a25e2a55206620ce

```
Adblock by BetaFish v3.31.2 [ID: gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom]
Chrome 67.0.3396.87
AngularJS & ngRoute: 1.7.2
```

-

```
but:
if I open my website in firefox (over localhost) -> no error
if I open my website in chrome (not over localhost) -> no error
if I click on normal link -> no error
if I disable adblock or remove adblock-datacollection-contentscript.js file -> no error
```

How to fix it also in chrome with adblock when my page is on localhost?

I haven't variable or const "chunkSize" in my code.

thanks for answers and sry for my bad English.

Comment: Looks like a scope issue, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699451/snippets-identifier-has-already-been-declared) will help you. Also as a side note, make sure it's not something related to chrome browser security.

Comment: it's not related to chrome browser security,... I also tried use flags:
--args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir -–allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: It could be another of you chrome extensions adding a `chunkSize` causing it? And it seems unlikely to be angularjs or ui-router since their code is readily available on github and there is no chunksize there. Which I suppose leaves your dependencies, extensions or maybe your build tools... And it must be pretty easy to search through your dependencies for something so specific so I'm guessing you have done that already.

Comment: I have only adblocker, no another extensions have. Yes, in angularJS and ngRoute don't containt any chunkSize variable or const. But it's happening only with ngRoute or ui-router with link with href value like "#!something". It's happend also with example from w3schools.com tutorial. If I click on normal link with href="https://www.google.com/" -> no error. Also no error when I use iframe with name and after target to this iframe. only with ngRoute It does error.

Comment: maybe it's solved,... https://help.getadblock.com/public/tickets/ee78ccfff325c4fb47aa0ae2056fe2d2096b738d657153837be39c31c615a4b8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED, it was bug in adblock.