# How to run the same snippet multiple times without page reload?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, code-snippets

I am playing with JavaScript in "Sources" tab in Google Chrome.
I have created this snippet:

```
const sayHello = () => console.log("Hello");
sayHello();
```

The problem is - I can run it only one time. If I clicked on "Run" button again - an error will be displayed in "Console":

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'sayHello' has already been declared
>       at :1:1

Of course I can Refresh the page each time before I ran the Snippet - but it's get tedious and I would much prefer another solution. Basically I want to write multi-line JS code and then execute it and see all its output in console.

Comment: The code in the post doesn't respond to button clicks. Please show the code for the "Run" button, and the related event handler code too ...

Comment: @Teemu, http://prntscr.com/kq1srs

Comment: I cant comment but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49914321/5972244) answer, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'var' instead of 'const'.

You cannot rewrite constants, they are read only.